# How does GCC optimize out an unused variable incremented inside a loop?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-optimization, disassembly

I wrote this simple C program:

```c
int main() {
    int i;
    int count = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < 2000000000; i++){
        count = count + 1;
    }
}
```

I wanted to see how the gcc compiler optimizes this loop (clearly add *1* 2000000000 times should be "add *2000000000* one time"). So:

**gcc test.c** and then `time` on `a.out` gives:

```
real 0m7.717s  
user 0m7.710s  
sys 0m0.000s
```

**$ gcc -O2 test.c**  and then `time on`a.out` gives:

```
real 0m0.003s  
user 0m0.000s  
sys 0m0.000s
```

Then I disassembled both with `gcc -S`. First one seems quite clear:

```
    .file "test.c"  
    .text  
.globl main
    .type   main, @function  
main:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movl    $0, -8(%rbp)
    movl    $0, -4(%rbp)
    jmp .L2
.L3:
    addl    $1, -8(%rbp)
    addl    $1, -4(%rbp)
.L2:
    cmpl    $1999999999, -4(%rbp)
    jle .L3
    leave
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.5.2-8ubuntu4) 4.5.2"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

L3 adds, L2 compare `-4(%rbp)` with `1999999999` and loops to L3 if `i < 2000000000`.

**Now the optimized one:**

```
    .file "test.c"  
    .text
    .p2align 4,,15
.globl main
    .type main, @function
main:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    rep
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size main, .-main
    .ident "GCC: (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.5.2-8ubuntu4) 4.5.2"
    .section .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

I can't understand at all what's going on there! I've got little knowledge of assembly, but I expected something like

```
addl $2000000000, -8(%rbp)
```

I even tried with **gcc -c -g -Wa,-a,-ad -O2 test.c** to see the C code together with the assembly it was converted to, but the result was no more clear that the previous one.

**Can someone briefly explain:**

1. The **gcc -S -O2** output.
2. If the loop is optimized as I expected (one sum instead of many sums)?

Comment: Nice question btw, and welcome to Stackoverflow! This, is a fine example of an excellent first question to ask. :)

Answer (score 73, accepted):

The compiler is even smarter than that. :)

In fact, it realizes that you aren't using the result of the loop. So it took out the entire loop completely!

This is called [Dead Code Elimination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_code_elimination).

A better test is to print the result:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    int i; int count = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < 2000000000; i++){
        count = count + 1;
    }

    //  Print result to prevent Dead Code Elimination
    printf("%d\n", count);
}
```

**EDIT :** I've added the required `#include <stdio.h>`; the MSVC assembly listing corresponds to a version without the `#include`, but it should be the same.

---

I don't have GCC in front of me at the moment, since I'm booted into Windows. But here's the disassembly of the version with the `printf()` on MSVC:

**EDIT : I had the wrong assembly output. Here's the correct one.**

```
; 57   : int main(){

$LN8:
    sub rsp, 40                 ; 00000028H

; 58   : 
; 59   : 
; 60   :     int i; int count = 0;
; 61   :     for(i = 0; i < 2000000000; i++){
; 62   :         count = count + 1;
; 63   :     }
; 64   : 
; 65   :     //  Print result to prevent Dead Code Elimination
; 66   :     printf("%d\n",count);

    lea rcx, OFFSET FLAT:??_C@_03PMGGPEJJ@?$CFd?6?$AA@
    mov edx, 2000000000             ; 77359400H
    call    QWORD PTR __imp_printf

; 67   : 
; 68   : 
; 69   : 
; 70   :
; 71   :     return 0;

    xor eax, eax

; 72   : }

    add rsp, 40                 ; 00000028H
    ret 0
```

So yes, Visual Studio does this optimization. I'd assume GCC probably does too.

And yes, GCC performs a similar optimization.  Here's an assembly listing for the same program with `gcc -S -O2 test.c` (gcc 4.5.2, Ubuntu 11.10, x86):

```
        .file   "test.c"
        .section        .rodata.str1.1,"aMS",@progbits,1
.LC0:
        .string "%d\n"
        .text
        .p2align 4,,15
.globl main
        .type   main, @function
main:
        pushl   %ebp
        movl    %esp, %ebp
        andl    $-16, %esp
        subl    $16, %esp
        movl    $2000000000, 8(%esp)
        movl    $.LC0, 4(%esp)
        movl    $1, (%esp)
        call    __printf_chk
        leave
        ret
        .size   main, .-main
        .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.5.2-8ubuntu4) 4.5.2"
        .section        .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Comment: Well, I feel really dumb right now. Didn't think (eew.. didn't know) about Dead code elimination. I tried with printf() and gcc, and it produces quite the same optimized code. Thank you for you answer!

Comment: Don't feel dumb. This kind of thing is not obvious at all if you're just getting into micro-benchmarking. It's just part of the learning process.

Comment: It would be interesting to know how the compiler makes this kind of decisions. What if that loop was really needed for some reason?

Comment: @marcushatchenson That's a pretty big compiler topic. The basic idea is that the compiler generates a [Dependency Graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_graph), which can then be used to prove/disprove whether certain computations are ever needed. Things that are proven to not be needed are then eliminated.

Comment: @marcushatchenson - the only effect the loop has is to increment `count`, which is a local variable. The C spec states that nothing outside the function is aware of the local, and the compiler knows that the function doesn't do anything with the result. By the rules of the spec, there's no possible effect on the program if `count` is not computed, so the optimizer is allowed to junk it. If you declare count as a global, on the other hand, the compiler has to treat it differently.

Comment: I am doing someting similar but my code deliberatelu uses the 'output' of the loop. I even use x=x+i and mixing with argv's. Non optimized version cycling for 5sec, yet -O9 doing it momentarily.

Answer (score 1):

Compilers have a few tools at their disposal to make code more efficient or more "efficient":

1. If the result of a computation is never used, the code that performs the computation can be omitted (if the computation acted upon `volatile` values, those values must still be read but the results of the read may be ignored).  If the results of the computations that fed it weren't used, the code that performs those can be omitted as well.  If such omission makes the code for both paths on a conditional branch identical, the condition may be regarded as unused and omitted.  This will have no effect on the behaviors (other than execution time) of any program that doesn't make out-of-bounds memory accesses or invoke what Annex L would call "Critical Undefined Behaviors".
2. If the compiler determines that the machine code that computes a value can only produce results in a certain range, it may omit any conditional tests whose outcome could be predicted on that basis.  As above, this will not affect behaviors other than execution time unless code invokes "Critical Undefined Behaviors".
3. If the compiler determines that certain inputs would invoke any form of Undefined Behavior with the code as written, the Standard would allow the compiler to omit any code which would only be relevant when such inputs are received, even if the natural behavior of the execution platform given such inputs would have been benign and the compiler's rewrite would make it dangerous.

Good compilers do #1 and #2.  For some reason, however, #3 has become fashionable.