# Why code with multiple nested loops can finish immediately on GCC but take forever on VS?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc, optimization, compiler-optimization

```
long long r = 0;
long long k = 0;
for (; k < 9999999999999; k++) 
{
    for (long long i = 0; i < 9999999999999; i++) 
    {
        for (long long j = 0; j < 9999999999999; j++) 
        {
            r = (r + (i * j) % 100) % 47;
            if (r != 0) 
            {
                r++;
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

This code executes on i3Core in 0.000001 wall seconds, checked with `boost::timer::auto_cpu_timer` on i7Core.

But with visual studio 2010 it seems to run in infinite time.

What is wrong with GCC or VS ? Is GCC optimizing too much?

Comment: is `r` being ever used?  It's probably discarded together with all loops.  See assembly.  If you want to ensure loop execution, print `r`

Comment: Note, the term "super optimization" is typically used for compilers that generate all possible combinations of something and pick the most efficient one.

Comment: too bad it's not even super-formatting your code ;-)

Comment: Sorry, didnt care about this test piece of code

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, GCC is optimizing that code.

Specifically, it knows that you aren't using the result, so it's removing all of it.
(You're never using the variable `r`.)

This is called [Dead Code Elimination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_code_elimination).

To prevent the compiler from optimizing it out, you'll need to use the result somehow. Try printing `r` out at the end:

```
cout << r << endl;
```

However, I warn that you'll need to reduce the iteration counts, or it probably won't finish in your lifetime.

---

I just tested this in VS2010 x64. Looking at the assembly, it is clear that ***VS2010 is not able to optimize out the entire loop***.

It goes to show that different compilers vary in their ability to optimize different things.

---

Related, and more in-depth: [How does GCC optimize out an unused variable incremented inside a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8841865/how-does-gcc-optimize-c-code)

Comment: Visual Studio not being able to optimize this completely is actually a bit scary... I'll test with VS11 Beta and report back.

Comment: Assigning to a `volatile` is also an option if you don't wish to print anything.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y That would work, though it would also block the compiler from doing mem-to-register promotion - which would probably nuke performance.

Comment: @Mystical, I just mean the final result -- yes, if used in the calculation you'd kill performance. Declare a global `volatile long long junk;` and then assign r to it `junk = r;`.

Comment: This is kinda depressing. Even after removing the outer two loops VS11 beta is not able to optimize the code out.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y Ah, ic. I didn't think about it that way. :-)

Comment: @Xeo Unless you're writing micro-benchmarks like this, it's very uncommon in actual code to have this much dead-code in such constructs. So I'd probably assume MS didn't find it worth it to implement the dependency analysis needed to prove that this loop is useless.

Comment: @Xeo: Clang 3.0 seems to only be able to remove one layer of loop, leaving the `i` and `j` loop it does not realizes that `r` is unused either :x

Comment: @Xeo: the problem for MSVC is the branch (the `if`), removing that leads to the loop being fully folded on my system (x64), for 32bit targets, the type of `i` & `j` needs to also be shortened to `long` for it to be folded (I assume this is cause of MSVC's `_all*` functions screwing things up)

Comment: Thanks for the answers, yes, with cout << r this code makes my computer cry =)

Comment: An obvious question: you're invoking VS with optimization flags, yes?

Comment: @KeithThompson It's been a long time. But I usually do these things in the default `/O2`.

Comment: According to [Microsoft's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1ack8f1.aspx), `/O2` "optimizes code for maximum speed", and there is no `/O3`. But there' also a `/Ox`, which "selects full optimization", whatever that means. I hesitate to assume that MSVS *can't* eliminate the dead code, but it's likely you're right.

Comment: @KeithThompson It can definitely do dead-code. But this case is probably too complicated for VS2010. Normal DCE will probably miss this case since `r` references itself. But ADCE will get it. ADCE is "aggressive DCE" which assumes that all variables are dead until proven alive. I can't say whether VS2010 does DCE, but not ADCE, but it's certainly a possible explanation.

Comment: Yes, by "the dead code" I was specifically referring to this example (I could have been clearer about that).

Answer (score 1):

**You are running undefined behaviour**

Your code has undefined behavior at `i * j` on most platforms because:

```
9999999999999 * 9999999999999 > 2^64
```

and `long long` is `2^64` on most platforms as there is simply too little hardware support for 128-bit integers.

Thanks to GCC -O3 for pointing this out in a warning: it can suppose that UB does not happen and run the loop less times. See also: [Why does this loop produce "warning: iteration 3u invokes undefined behavior" and output more than 4 lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24296571/why-does-this-loop-produce-warning-iteration-3u-invokes-undefined-behavior-an)

So anything can happen.

**Let's decompile it to see what is really happening**

GCC 4.8:

```
gcc -c -g -std=c99 -O0 a.c
objudmp -S a.o
```

Output:

```
a.o:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <main>:
int main() {
   0:   55                      push   %rbp
   1:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
    long long r = 0;
   4:   48 c7 45 e0 00 00 00    movq   $0x0,-0x20(%rbp)
   b:   00 
    long long k = 0;
   c:   48 c7 45 e8 00 00 00    movq   $0x0,-0x18(%rbp)
  13:   00 
    for (; k < 9999999999999; k++) 
  14:   e9 f8 00 00 00          jmpq   111 <main+0x111>
    {
        for (long long i = 0; i < 9999999999999; i++) 
  19:   48 c7 45 f0 00 00 00    movq   $0x0,-0x10(%rbp)
  20:   00 
  21:   e9 d2 00 00 00          jmpq   f8 <main+0xf8>
        {
            for (long long j = 0; j < 9999999999999; j++) 
  26:   48 c7 45 f8 00 00 00    movq   $0x0,-0x8(%rbp)
  2d:   00 
  2e:   e9 ac 00 00 00          jmpq   df <main+0xdf>
            {
                r = (r + (i * j) % 100) % 47;
  33:   48 8b 45 f0             mov    -0x10(%rbp),%rax
  37:   48 0f af 45 f8          imul   -0x8(%rbp),%rax
  3c:   48 89 c1                mov    %rax,%rcx
  3f:   48 ba 0b d7 a3 70 3d    movabs $0xa3d70a3d70a3d70b,%rdx
  46:   0a d7 a3 
  49:   48 89 c8                mov    %rcx,%rax
  4c:   48 f7 ea                imul   %rdx
  4f:   48 8d 04 0a             lea    (%rdx,%rcx,1),%rax
  53:   48 c1 f8 06             sar    $0x6,%rax
  57:   48 89 c2                mov    %rax,%rdx
  5a:   48 89 c8                mov    %rcx,%rax
  5d:   48 c1 f8 3f             sar    $0x3f,%rax
  61:   48 29 c2                sub    %rax,%rdx
  64:   48 89 d0                mov    %rdx,%rax
  67:   48 c1 e0 02             shl    $0x2,%rax
  6b:   48 01 d0                add    %rdx,%rax
  6e:   48 8d 14 85 00 00 00    lea    0x0(,%rax,4),%rdx
  75:   00 
  76:   48 01 d0                add    %rdx,%rax
  79:   48 c1 e0 02             shl    $0x2,%rax
  7d:   48 29 c1                sub    %rax,%rcx
  80:   48 89 ca                mov    %rcx,%rdx
  83:   48 8b 45 e0             mov    -0x20(%rbp),%rax
  87:   48 8d 0c 02             lea    (%rdx,%rax,1),%rcx
  8b:   48 ba 99 5c 41 4c ae    movabs $0x572620ae4c415c99,%rdx
  92:   20 26 57 
  95:   48 89 c8                mov    %rcx,%rax
  98:   48 f7 ea                imul   %rdx
  9b:   48 c1 fa 04             sar    $0x4,%rdx
  9f:   48 89 c8                mov    %rcx,%rax
  a2:   48 c1 f8 3f             sar    $0x3f,%rax
  a6:   48 29 c2                sub    %rax,%rdx
  a9:   48 89 d0                mov    %rdx,%rax
  ac:   48 89 45 e0             mov    %rax,-0x20(%rbp)
  b0:   48 8b 55 e0             mov    -0x20(%rbp),%rdx
  b4:   48 89 d0                mov    %rdx,%rax
  b7:   48 01 c0                add    %rax,%rax
  ba:   48 01 d0                add    %rdx,%rax
  bd:   48 c1 e0 04             shl    $0x4,%rax
  c1:   48 29 d0                sub    %rdx,%rax
  c4:   48 29 c1                sub    %rax,%rcx
  c7:   48 89 c8                mov    %rcx,%rax
  ca:   48 89 45 e0             mov    %rax,-0x20(%rbp)
                if (r != 0) 
  ce:   48 83 7d e0 00          cmpq   $0x0,-0x20(%rbp)
  d3:   74 05                   je     da <main+0xda>
                {
                    r++;
  d5:   48 83 45 e0 01          addq   $0x1,-0x20(%rbp)
    long long k = 0;
    for (; k < 9999999999999; k++) 
    {
        for (long long i = 0; i < 9999999999999; i++) 
        {
            for (long long j = 0; j < 9999999999999; j++) 
  da:   48 83 45 f8 01          addq   $0x1,-0x8(%rbp)
  df:   48 b8 fe 9f 72 4e 18    movabs $0x9184e729ffe,%rax
  e6:   09 00 00 
  e9:   48 39 45 f8             cmp    %rax,-0x8(%rbp)
  ed:   0f 8e 40 ff ff ff       jle    33 <main+0x33>
int main() {
    long long r = 0;
    long long k = 0;
    for (; k < 9999999999999; k++) 
    {
        for (long long i = 0; i < 9999999999999; i++) 
  f3:   48 83 45 f0 01          addq   $0x1,-0x10(%rbp)
  f8:   48 b8 fe 9f 72 4e 18    movabs $0x9184e729ffe,%rax
  ff:   09 00 00 
 102:   48 39 45 f0             cmp    %rax,-0x10(%rbp)
 106:   0f 8e 1a ff ff ff       jle    26 <main+0x26>
int main() {
    long long r = 0;
    long long k = 0;
    for (; k < 9999999999999; k++) 
 10c:   48 83 45 e8 01          addq   $0x1,-0x18(%rbp)
 111:   48 b8 fe 9f 72 4e 18    movabs $0x9184e729ffe,%rax
 118:   09 00 00 
 11b:   48 39 45 e8             cmp    %rax,-0x18(%rbp)
 11f:   0f 8e f4 fe ff ff       jle    19 <main+0x19>
 125:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
                    r++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
 12a:   5d                      pop    %rbp
 12b:   c3                      retq
```

so all the loops seems present.

With `-O3`:

```
0000000000000000 <main>:
   0:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
   2:   c3                      retq
```

so it was clearly optimized away. Nothing in the C standard prevents that optimization, so GCC does it.

If we add a `printf("%lld", r);` at the end as mentioned by Mystical, it does take forever even with `-O3`, and the generated optimized code is almost the same as the non optimized one.

For infinite loops it gets more interesting: [Are compilers allowed to eliminate infinite loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178115/are-compilers-allowed-to-eliminate-infinite-loops)

How to prevent if from happening: [How to prevent GCC from optimizing out a busy wait loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7083482/how-to-prevent-compiler-optimization-on-a-small-piece-of-code)