# C++ boost::thread that never quits

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

My int main uses a while (1) loop to run my code.  If I want to start continuous threads before I enter my while loop, would it look like this?

```
int main ()
{
     boost::thread_group threads;
     threads.create_thread (check_database);
     while (1)
     {
          // main program
     }
}

void check_database_and_plc ()
{
     while (1)
     {
          // check database, and if it needs to take action, do so;
          // this function / thread will never stop;
          // it will continuously check a single value from mysql and take
          // action based on that number (if 1, write to PLC, if 2, change
          // screens, etc);
          // also check plc for any errors, if there are any, tell int main
     }
}
```

Therefore I have two while loops running at the same time.  Is there a better way to do this?  Thank you for your time.

Comment: Looks fine. You might want to add some interrupt/stop condition, though. And don't forget to correctly protect the database, so that access (read/write) to it is thread-safe.
Edit: on second thought, if the change in the database is caused by some specific action in `main`, you can use `signal()` and `wait()` methods to prevent the `check_database()` from using CPU if not needed.

Comment: how would I do that exactly?

Comment: do they have a happen-before relationship?

Comment: @sinthose: Relevant links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25082563/using-a-boost-thread-signal-and-wait-for-termination ; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16907072/how-do-i-use-a-boost-condition-variable-to-wait-for-a-thread-to-complete-process

Comment: I am not quite sure what your requirements are.

Comment: no, but if I wanted to return a value from check_database to int main if it sees something, how would I do that?

Comment: @xinthose What do you mean by "return a value from check_database to int main if it sees something"?
Complete code and goals would be helpful.

Comment: sorry; so if check_database_and_plc sees an error in my plc, it should tell int main immediately somehow.  I could just write a bit to mysql and read it from int main

Comment: Look at my answer. Feel free to further ask if it does not match your requirements.

Comment: Why would you mix DB and PLC checks? I'd move that into two threads, so you can also configure the interval between the checks more freely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From you comment, I would (as a first try!) understand you need something like this:

```
bool plc_error = false;
boost::condition_variable cv;
boost::mutex mutex;
int main ()
{
     boost::thread_group threads;
     threads.create_thread (check_database);
     while (1)
     {

          boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(mutex);
          while(!plc_error)
              cv.wait(lock);
          // deal with the error
          plc_error = false;
     }
}

void check_database_and_plc ()
{
     while (1)
     {
          // sleep a bit to ensure main will not miss notify_one()
          // check database and plc
          if (error){
              plc_error = true;
              cv.notify_one();
          }
     }
}
```

I did not take into account terminating and joining the thread into `main`, but the links I gave in the comments should help you.

Comment: You' re welcome. This is common for multithreaded programming - I would suggest reading a bit of theory on the subject (keywords: threads, synchronization, mutexs, semaphores, condition variables, or some Operating Systems course/textbook), it will give you the best tools to solve optimally your problem. It is very important, since concurrent programming is much less intuitive than serial (regular?) coding.

Comment: so if at any point in int main's while (1) loop, plc_error is true, it will immediately go to the second while(!plc_error) loop, deal with the error, set it back to false, then continue on with the while (1) loop?

Comment: No. The `check()` thread will send a "notification" to any other thread waiting for a notification, and then go on with execution. Since here we have only two threads, it will "wake up" the `main()` thread, which is sleeping until it receives a message.