# Is an implementation that allows you turn off diagnostics required by the standard still conforming?

Tags: c, clang, language-lawyer

Consider the following:

```
typedef int;
int main () { return 0; }
```

If I compile this with clang with no warning specifications I get

```
warning: typedef requires a name [-Wmissing-declarations]
typedef int;
```

That's to be expected; `typedef int` is illegal per section 6.7 of the C11 standard, and per section 5.1.1.3,

> A conforming implementation shall produce at least one diagnostic message if a preprocessing translation unit or translation unit contains a violation of any syntax rule or constraint.

If I compile this using `clang -Wno-missing-declarations`, it compiles clean, without any diagnostic messages.

**My question:**
Does this mark clang as a non-conforming implementation, or is it okay to provide the ability to disable what would otherwise be mandatory diagnostics?

Comment: It seems to me that if anything, clang is conforming just fine and it allows you to specify a flag that makes your use of it non-conforming.

Comment: Related to [Does C standard mandate that platforms must not define behaviors beyond those given in standard](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29830201/1708801)

Comment: GCC also allows this however you have to write some other non-conforming code (using implicit int in C99, for example) as quite a few such diagnostics don't have a name/option in GCC.

Comment: You could say that `clang -Wno-missing-declarations` is for all intents and purposes a different compiler than `clang`. Same for `gcc -ansi -pedantic` vs `gcc`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the draft C11 standard section `4` *Conformance* we see that it is not strictly conforming:

> A strictly conforming program shall use only those features of the
>   language and library specified in this International Standard.3) It
>   shall not produce output dependent on any unspecified, undefined, or
>   implementation-defined behavior, and shall not exceed any minimum
>   implementation limit.

but it is a conforming implementation since a conforming implementation is allowed to have extensions as long as they don't break a strictly conforming program:

> [...]A conforming implementation may have extensions (including
>   additional library functions), provided they do not alter the behavior
>   of any strictly conforming program.<sup>4)</sup>

The [C-FAQ says](http://c-faq.com/ansi/compliance.html):

> [...]There are very few realistic, useful, strictly conforming programs. On the other hand, a merely conforming program can make use of any compiler-specific extension it wants to.

Comment: This makes sense. In a similar vein, I see that gcc has the option `-Wno-endif-labels` (clang: `-Wno-extra-tokens`) that bypasses the diagnostic on constructs such as `#endif foo`. Strictly speaking, those labels are illegal. On the other hand, there's lots of legacy code that is loaded with them. Caveat compiler user when it comes to disabling compiler warnings.