# g++ "warning: iteration ... invokes undefined behavior" for Seemingly Unrelated Variable

Tags: c++, g++, compiler-warnings

Consider the following code in `strange.cpp`:

```
#include <vector> 


using namespace std;


int i = 0;


int *bar()
{   
    ++i;
    return &i; 
}   


int main()
{   
    for(size_t j = 0; j < 99999999999; ++j) // (*)
    {   
        const auto p = bar();
        if(!p) // (**)
            return -1; 
    }   
}
```

Compiling this with g++ gives a warning:

```
$ g++ --std=c++11 -O3 strange.cpp 
strange.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
strange.cpp:12:12: warning: iteration 4294967296ul invokes undefined behavior [-Waggressive-loop-optimizations]
         ++i;
            ^
strange.cpp:19:9: note: containing loop
         for(size_t j = 0; j < 99999999999; ++j) // (*)
         ^
```

I don't understand why the increment invokes undefined behavior. Moreover, there are two changes, each of which makes the warning disappear:

1. changing the line `(*)` to `for(int j...`
2. changing the line `(**)` to `if(!*p)`

What is the meaning of this warning, and why are the changes relevant to it?

**Note**

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) 4.8.4
```

Comment: Your "solution" number 1 (using `int` instead of `size_t` for the loop variable) will lead to signed integer overflow, which is undefined behavior.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg not that I disagree, however it's not a solution, rather a change (admittedly problematic) to one variable, that removes a warning for a completely different variable. So thanks for the comment, but it doesn't shed light on it for me.

Comment: I did not manage to reproduce this issue with `g++ (Debian 4.7.2-5) 4.7.2`...

Comment: Neither change is an actual solution - the second one causes the loop to exit immediately without ever being called. You can see this from the generated assembly code. When you use `(!*p)`, the program exits with `-1`; the optimizer detects this case from the first iteration of the loop

Comment: @francis I appreciate your effort in checking this, though. Thanks.

Comment: @Petesh Thanks for checking the generated assembly code (I don't know how to read it), and for your comment/answer. Just, for clarification, I did not propose these as solutions, just as things I couldn't see why their change should affect an unrelated variable.

Comment: In trying to collapse the loop in the optimizer, it actually detects the int overflow in `bar()`, which is why the complaint happens. You can explicitly define int overflow behaviour using `-fwrapv`, which will also eliminate the warning. ecatmur's answer explains the default behavior.

Comment: Many thanks, @Petesh!

Comment: what is `SIZE_MAX` on your platform?

Comment: @M.M How can I tell? I would normally print it, but as what type? Thanks.

Comment: @M.M I did `find /usr/include/c++ -name '*' | xargs grep 'SIZE_MAX'`, but there was no output.

Comment: `cout << SIZE_MAX << '\n';` after including iostream and climits. Or `cout << sizeof(size_t) << '\n';`

Comment: Thanks, @M.M - The output of the latter was 8.

Comment: Closely related to [Why does this loop produce “warning: iteration 3u invokes undefined behavior” and output more than 4 lines?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24296571/1708801)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The increment is undefined because once `i` reaches [`std::numeric_limits<int>::max()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/max) (2<sup>31</sup> - 1 on a 32-bit, LP64 or LLP64 platform), incrementing it will overflow, which is undefined behavior for signed integral types.

gcc is warning on iteration 4294967296ul (2<sup>32</sup>) rather than iteration 2147483646u (2<sup>31</sup>) as you might expect, because it *doesn't know the initial value of `i`*; some other code might have run before `main` to set `i` to something other than `0`. But once `main` is entered, no other code can run to alter `i`, and so once 2<sup>32</sup> iterations have completed it will have at some point reached 2<sup>31</sup> - 1 and overflowed.

1. "fixes" it by turning the controlling condition of the loop into a tautologically true expression; this makes the loop an infinite loop, since the `if` inside the loop will never execute, as `&i` cannot be a null pointer. [Infinite loops can be optimized away](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178115/are-compilers-allowed-to-eliminate-infinite-loops), so gcc eliminates the body of the loop and the integer overflow of `i` does not occur.
2. "fixes" it by allowing gcc an out from the undefined behavior of integer overflow. The only way to prevent integer overflow is for `i` to have an initial value that is negative, such that at some point `i` reaches zero. This is possible (see above), and the only alternative is undefined behavior, so it *must* happen. So `i` reaches zero, the `if` inside the loop executes, and `main` returns `-1`.

Comment: To be clear, the two "fixes" both still cause undefined behaviour, it's just that no warning is printed .  There's no other code present that could modify `i` before `main`  (and the compiler apparently doesn't try to use that information).