# A nonobvious cause for "iteration ... invokes undefined behavior [-Waggressive-loop-optimizations]"warning

Tags: c, gcc, x86-64

When investigating a problem, I stumbled upon code, which boils down to the following example:

```
const unsigned long long int MAX=9223372036854775807ULL; //2^63-1
void double_it(double *d){
for(unsigned long long int i=0;i<MAX; i++){
       d[i]=2*d[i];      
    }
}
```

Due to some mistakes, the for loop runs much further than there is memory and the program crashes. But this is not the interesting part.

When compiled with gcc (`gcc  -O2 -Wall -std=c99 -c`), this code leads to the following warning:

> warning: iteration 2305843009213693951ull invokes undefined behavior [-Waggressive-loop-optimizations]

which cause I don't understand.

There are some similar questions on stackoverflow, e.g.:

1. [g++ "warning: iteration ... invokes undefined behavior" for Seemingly Unrelated Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35299041/g-warning-iteration-invokes-undefined-behavior-for-seemingly-unrelated)
2. [Why does this loop produce "warning: iteration 3u invokes undefined behavior" and output more than 4 lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24296571/why-does-this-loop-produce-warning-iteration-3u-invokes-undefined-behavior-an)

But those problems were integer overflows, here  the counter `i` is seemingly nowhere near an overflow.

Compiling the same code without `-O2` does not lead to such a warning, so I guess `-Waggressive-loop-optimizations` is an important part.

So actually, I have two questions:

1. What is the problem with this code (compiled for Linux x86-64)?
2. Why there is no warning without `-O2`? If this code is faulty, I would expect it to be faulty no matter whether it is optimized or not.

---

The behavior is the same for g++ (see it online at [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/035cbb496c2f530b)).

Comment: Do you think your computer has around 8388600 __terabytes__ of RAM or more?

Comment: Don't use hand-crafted constants. `limits.h` provides `ULLONG_MAX`, why not use it?

Comment: *"Why there is no warning without -O2? If this code is faulty, I would expect it to be faulty no matter whether it is optimized or not."* gcc does not track everything it can when the optimizer is not enabled, probably to speed up compilation of debug builds. This prominently includes uninitialized variables. The code itself would be broken both in debug and release of course, but you'd only get a diagnostic in release.

Comment: @ForceBru I know it is not a very practical question... but if I had?

Comment: @ead, then you'd probably need something like g++ 14.0.6 or newer. I think g++ does some optimizations that rely on the maximum memory available, but I might be wrong.

Comment: @BaummitAugen: More likely because the corresponding information is not available if the optimisation code is not run. There is no requirement to emit diagnostics by tghe standard, these warnings are a "courtesy" of gcc, nothing else.

Comment: You forgot to mention the platform. Why not use `size_t` and `SIZE_MAX` which are the correct types/limits for array-indexes.

Comment: @Olaf the platform is the usual x86-64 Linux

Comment: @Olaf I just try to keep the example minimal

Comment: That has nothing to do with "minimal", but with a correct example. You just use the wrong types and (possibly) the wrong limits. You just cannot assume all values of an `unsigned long long` are valid indexes for an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But those problems were integer overflows, here the counter i is seemingly nowhere near an overflow.

Why would you think that?

`d[i]` is the same as `*(d + i)`. `d + i` clearly overflows since the size of a double is more than 2 (not exactly sure if that's spelled out anywhere in the standard, but it's a pretty safe assumption that your architecture is like that). To be perfectly correct, sizeof is not entirely related to this, but this is what the code gets turned into internally in the compiler.

In C11 §6.5.6 we can read:

> If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the behavior is undefined

We can reverse the logic of that sentence. If the addition obviously overflows, then it must have been undefined behavior.

The reason why you don't get a warning is that the compiler is under no obligation to give you a warning on all undefined behaviors. It's a courtesy from the compiler. With optimizations the compiler spends more time reasoning about what your code does, so it gets the chance to spot more bad behaviors. Without optimizations it doesn't waste time doing that.