# Why is an array so much faster than a vector?

Tags: c++, arrays, performance, vector

Is this a fair test for comparing a vector with an array? The difference in speed seems too large. My test suggests the array is 10 to 100 times faster!

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdint.h>

using namespace std;

double PCFreq = 0.0;
__int64 CounterStart = 0;

using namespace std;

void StartCounter()
{
    LARGE_INTEGER li;
    if(!QueryPerformanceFrequency(&li))
    std:cout << "QueryPerformanceFrequency failed!\n";

    PCFreq = double(li.QuadPart)/1000000000;

    QueryPerformanceCounter(&li);
    CounterStart = li.QuadPart;
}
double GetCounter()
{
    LARGE_INTEGER li;
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&li);
    return double(li.QuadPart-CounterStart)/PCFreq;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    //Can do 100,000 but not 1,000,000
    const int vectorsize = 100000;
    cout.precision(10);

    StartCounter();
    vector<int> test1(vectorsize);
    for(int i=0; i<vectorsize; i++){
        test1[i] = 5;
    }
    cout << GetCounter() << endl << endl;


    StartCounter();
    int test2[vectorsize];
    for(int i=0; i<vectorsize; i++){
        test2[i] = 5;
    }
    cout << GetCounter() << endl << endl;

    cout << test2[0];

    int t = 0;
    cin >> t;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Look at the assembly code.  Chances are, almost everything is optimized out in a release build.

Comment: Indeed, it's very likely that your second loop is being completely removed by the compiler.

Comment: When I run in release the second loop takes 0 "nanoseconds". Why is it being removed- because test2 just isnt being used?

Comment: @user997112 Correct. It's called [Dead Code Elimination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_code_elimination). Here's another example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8841865/how-does-gcc-optimize-c-code

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your numbers. Both times are coming to `0` for me. The compiler is generating a `rep stosd` instruction for both loops. So it's extremely fast. You need an outer-loop to make the benchmark take more time. I suspect your benchmark is taking less than a millisecond - which in that case, it's useless because that's much less than the uncertainty.

Comment: @user997112: The fact that you see this sort of difference probably indicates that you run some sort of debug build, non-optimized (or even deliberately de-optimized) and heavily overloaded with assertions (iterator checks and stuff like that). It makes absolutely no sense to run any comparisons in debug builds.

Comment: One difference is that the vector elements are first initialized to zero in the constructor, and then assigned the value 5. Try `vector<int> test1(vectorsize, 5);` instead.

Comment: Now I can reproduce your numbers. +1 for SSCCE.

Comment: @BoPersson that's it! I removed the array/vector creation statements from the timings and the vector is faster?!

Comment: The vector allocates its memory on the heap, while the static array is stored on the stack. If you want a fair comparison, you should either move the memory allocation out of the measurement or allocate both blocks on the heap.

Comment: Array *is* faster than a vector, and it is indeed tricky to benchmark properly. The example used in this test (i.e. copying the same value into all elements sequentially) is simply not good for demonstrating the difference. Here is the older question about the nature of that difference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2740020/c-stl-array-vs-vector-raw-element-accessing-performance. By tailoring your test case to better exploit that difference you can easily show that array is faster.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It depends on what you are comparing.

Your benchmark measures both *setup* time and *access* times together. It's doubtless that `std::vector` has a more expensive setup time. This is because it needs to allocate memory, and then (by necessity of the standard) call default constructors on all the elements. Which for a POD type, means zeroing.

So if you're trying to measure access times, then no your benchmark isn't accurate.

Here's some numbers to digest:

**Original Code:**

```
StartCounter();
vector<int> test1(vectorsize);

for(int i=0; i<vectorsize; i++){
    test1[i] = 5;
}
cout << GetCounter() << endl << endl;
```

**Time: 444353.5206**

---

Start timing *after* declaring and initializing the `vector`:

```
vector<int> test1(vectorsize);

StartCounter();
for(int i=0; i<vectorsize; i++){
    test1[i] = 5;
}
cout << GetCounter() << endl << endl;
```

**Time: 15031.76101**

---

And for the array:

```
StartCounter();
int test2[vectorsize];
for(int i=0; i<vectorsize; i++){
    test2[i] = 5;
}
cout << GetCounter() << endl << endl;
```

**Time: 38129.345**

The times are about the same regardless of whether the declaration is timed. This is likely because stack allocation is done all at once upon entry to the function.

---

Basically, the vector memory allocation and initialization is taking a disproportionate amount of time. But the actual loop is fast.

I'll also note that your current benchmark framework is still sightly flawed. You only make one pass over each array. So cache-effects and lazy-allocation will be significant.

The reason why the array is now slower is likely due to lazy-allocation. The array is allocated, but it hasn't been committed yet. Lazy allocation means that it is committed upon first access - which involves a page-fault and a context-switch to the kernel.

---

Here's a fairer test with an outer loop to increase the benchmark time:

```
vector<int> test1(vectorsize);

StartCounter();
for (int c = 0; c < 10000; c++){
    for(int i=0; i<vectorsize; i++){
        test1[i] = 5;
    }
}
cout << GetCounter() << endl << endl;
```

**Time: 227330454.6**

```
int test2[vectorsize];
memset(test2,0,sizeof(test2));

StartCounter();
for (int c = 0; c < 10000; c++){
    for(int i=0; i<vectorsize; i++){
        test2[i] = 5;
    }
}
cout << GetCounter() << endl << endl;
cout << test2[0];
```

**Time: 212286228.2**

So no an array is ***NOT*** faster than a vector for steady-state access. It's just tricky to benchmark properly.

Comment: what about starting the array counter after the declaration also? to make both loops start the counter at the same point in time.

Comment: @Need4Sleep I did it both ways. There was no performance difference. That's because the array is on the stack and is allocated upon entry to the function.

Comment: Removing both initializations from the timing, why would the vector then be faster than the static array loop? Im looking at the release assembler and the static array loop only has 2x MOVs, 1x LEA and 1 repo stos instructions?

Comment: @user997112 That's probably because the array probably isn't paged yet due to lazy allocation. [So the OS needs to zero it upon committing it due to security reasons.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8029584/why-does-malloc-initialize-the-values-to-0-in-gcc)

Comment: I actually just ran the benchmark a few more times and the results are very chaotic. The benchmark is simply too short. But overall these numbers here are representable of the average case.

Comment: @Mysticial. Thanks. I just tested one last thing. If I create an int array on the heap using int* test3 = new int[vectorsize] and then do the same test, with the timing not including initialization I get much slower performance. The assembler output shows no instructions for the FOR loop??

Comment: @user997112 Again it goes back to lazy allocation. Until you access the memory the first time, it is not really "allocated". So its customary to manually zero all newly allocated memory to remove this effect.

Comment: Anyways, I have a final in half an hour. So I won't be able to respond for a few hours.

Comment: Array *is* faster than a vector, and it is indeed tricky to benchmark properly. The example used in this test (i.e. copying the same value into all elements sequentially) is simply not good for demonstrating the difference. Here is an older question about the nature of that difference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2740020/c-stl-array-vs-vector-raw-element-accessing-performance. By tailoring your test case to better exploit that difference you can easily show that array is faster.

Comment: @AndreyT how difficult would it be to create a vector class which does not initialize values (as seen in this example if the timing includes the vector creation)?

Comment: Also, it is not practically possible for a vector to be faster than an array. If you results indicate that vector is faster, it is just a random fluke in your measurements.

Comment: @user997112: There's nothing difficult about it. Just don't initialize the values in your vector class and they will remain uninitialized. `std::vector`, unfortunately, unconditionally initializes the values. With `int` values and `std::vector` you can try a hack: instead of setting the vector's *size* try setting its *capacity* (keeping the size at `0`). This will technically allocate an *uninitialized* array. But keep in mind that in debug builds any attempts to access beyond the current size (which must stay at `0`) will probably trigger assertions.

Comment: @AndreyT I'll take a closer look at your answer after my exam. Since at first glance an extra move (which I'm not 100% convinced is necessary will make a difference in any real application. I'll also update my answer to mention that the setup cost of a vector is significant if that matters in an application that does little raw access.

Comment: @AndreyT Okay, that extra move in your answer only applies to the *first* access. After that, any self-respecting compiler will keep it in register and thus it effectively becomes a pointer. So we're both right. There *is* an extra move - but it's a startup cost. The steady-state is still the same.

Comment: @Mystical: Demand zero paged pages aren't actually zeroed on demand. The kernel zeroes them in the background and just allocates one from the previously background-zeroed pages. The cost you're thinking of is the 12000 cycles to interrupt, go through the paging code, add a new page into the process address space, flush the MMU and return back to usermode. Also, it's quite unlikely that this is the case. Stack pages are almost always paged in, as are heap allocations you just obtained. std::vector doesn't allocate from the kernel. It allocates from the heap.

Comment: @SecurityMatt That's interesting. Which seems to run contrary to what I've seen. When I allocate + commit 60GB on my workstation, it takes a full 30 seconds. But freeing it takes 5 seconds. Could this be OS dependent?

Comment: @Mystical If you overallocate you might run the kernel zero pool down to empty, at which point you might find your thread descheduled until the pool has replenished. A better test is to try timing a one page alloc versus a one page free followed with a thread sleep between test instances to give the zero pool time to replenish. This behaviour has been the case since at least Windows 2000 and is documented in the Windows Internals series of books.

Comment: @SecurityMatt Ah ic. That would explain it - since 60GB (out of a 64GB machine) is likely to empty to the pool. I guess I learned something new today. :)